# Is summation of some binary invertible matrices, invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A and B be 2×2 matrices over $Z$. If A, A+B, A+2B, A+3B, A+4B are invertible, and all the elements of their inverses are integer. Show that A+5B is invertible and all its elements are integer.

We know that A, A+B and A+4B are invertible can I conclude that (A+B) + (A+4B) - A is invertible?

Comment: No, you can't. However you need to clarify the question. Are they matrices over $\Bbb R$ with values $0$ and $1$, or matrices over $\Bbb Z_2$?

Comment: That you state that "all elements of their inverses are integer" seems to indicate that either you don't really understand the question or something very odd happens here: if the matrices are in $\;\Bbb Z_2=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$ then integers have no business here: the elements are residues modulo two, that's all!

Comment: I.m sorry. I typed the question wrong. The matrices are over integer numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your question is valid. You are working over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, which means that $A + 5B = A +B$ which is invertible by your hypothesis.

This is because if $B= \begin{pmatrix}
b_0 & b_1\\ 
b_2 & b_3 
\end{pmatrix}$, then $5B = \begin{pmatrix}
5b_0 & 5b_1\\ 
5b_2 & 5b_3 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
b_0 & b_1\\ 
b_2 & b_3 
\end{pmatrix} = B$.